# Como localizar um objeto somente pelo nome?

Tags: c#, winforms, instanciar-objeto, picturebox

Tenho 6 `PictureBox`, então, ao salvar a foto no banco de dados, salvo junto em qual `PictureBox` ela estava.

Então, ao carregar as fotos em uma visualização, preciso que cada foto seja apresentada em seu respectivo `PictureBox`, realizo a consulta no banco de dados atribuindo os valores ao `List` chamado `VetorImagem`.

Retorno um `array` de `byte` e o nome do `PictureBox` onde a foto estava.

Então para montar a foto e exibir no `PictureBox`, utilizo o codigo abaixo:`

```
//Crio o List chamado VetorImagem.
List<Classes.Dictionary.Crm.List_Photo_Crm> vetorImagem = new List<Classes.Dictionary.Crm.List_Photo_Crm>();
//Instancio minha classe de consulto ao banco de dados.
Classes.Dictionary.Crm.Analise_Crm Dic_foto = new Classes.Dictionary.Crm.Analise_Crm();
//realizo a consulta e associo ao List VetorImagem
vetorImagem = Dic_foto.preenche_fotos(textEdit8.Text);`

for(int a = 0; a < vetorImagem.Count; a++)
{

            //defini um nome de arquivo
            string strNomeArquivo = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.Write(vetorImagem[a].photo, 0, vetorImagem[a].photo.Length);

                stream.Flush(); 

                vetorImagem[a].PictureBox_Name.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                vetorImagem[a].PictureBox_Name.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                stream.Close();
            }
}
```

Porém, como faço para localizar o `PictureBox`?
Pois, ao utilizar `vetorImagem[a].PictureBox_Name` eu so tenho o nome do objeto.

Comment: você já tem os 6 picturebox na tela, ou vai coloca-los em tempo de execução ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eles já existem, preciso apenas "chama-los"

Comment: na verdade você não tem que instanciar eles, apenas localizar a instancia já existente no form (é winforms correto?), veja a resposta que coloquei

Comment: Correto, perfeito. obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há outras formas de fazer, mas na sua situação você pode usar o Find():

```
((PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("PictureBoxName", false)[0]).Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

considerando que o PictureBox esteja diretamente no Form.

Se estiver dentro de um `panel`, por exemplo, Troque o `this` pela instância do `panel`